# Reducer or Action not working

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm having a problem here, I have been doing redux for about 2 weeks now.

I'm trying to create a loader so I am trying to get the isFetching state. Using thunk, i'm doing an ajax fetch, and dispatching the loading state.

The dispatch was called, because I can see in my console.

before component will mount, its suppose to call FETCH_PROFILE, and isFetching set to true, but when i console.log(this.props.profile.isFetching), **it's returning false.**

Same for FETCH_PROFILE_SUCCESS, it doesn't update this.props.profile. (Or because It's not rerendering...so I can't see it)

I've been working on this simple thing for hours and I have no idea why it doesn't update...... I am sure I made some mistake somewhere but no idea what.

```
export const FETCH_PROFILE = 'FETCH_PROFILE';
export const FETCH_PROFILE_SUCCESS = 'FETCH_PROFILE_SUCCESS';
export const FETCH_PROFILE_FAIL = 'FETCH_PROFILE_FAIL';


export function getUserProfile() {


           return (dispatch) => {
                dispatch(getUserProfileStart());
                const config2 = {
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
                    credentials: 'include',
                    body: ``,
                };

              fetch('http://api.example.com/profile/',config2)
              .then((resp) => resp.json())
              .then(function(data) {        

               dispatch(getUserProfileSuccess(data));
               return 0;

            }).catch(function(error){

                return dispatch({type: FETCH_PROFILE_FAIL});
            })

}
}


function getUserProfileSuccess(data) {
    return {
        type: FETCH_PROFILE_SUCCESS,
        isFetching: false,
        payload: data
    }
}

function getUserProfileStart() {
    return {
        type: FETCH_PROFILE,
        isFetching: true
    }
}
```

my reducer

```
import {
  FETCH_PROFILE,
  FETCH_PROFILE_SUCCESS,
  FETCH_PROFILE_FAIL
} from '../actions/profile';


export default function userProfile(state={isFetching: false}, action) {


  switch(action.type) {

      case FETCH_PROFILE:

        return {...state, isFetching: true}

      case FETCH_PROFILE_SUCCESS:

         return {...state, isFetching: false, data: action.payload}

      case FETCH_PROFILE_FAIL:
         return { ...state, isFetching: false };

      default:
        return state


  }
}
```

My Component.

```
import React from 'react';
import withStyles from 'isomorphic-style-loader/lib/withStyles';
import {connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as profileActions from '../../actions/profile';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';  

class ProfilePage extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.getUserProfile = this.getUserProfile.bind(this);

    }

    componentWillMount() {

      this.props.actions.getUserProfile();
    }


  render() {
    console.log('Checking isFetching State', this.props.profile.isFetching);
    return (

      <div>

       some text here.
      </div>

    );
  }
}


function mapStateToProps(state) {
  console.log('Mapping Stat', state.profile);
  return {
    profile: state.userProfile
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {  
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(profileActions, dispatch)
  };
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withStyles(s)(ProfilePage));
```

my combine reducers...

```
import userProfile from './profile';
//some other imports...
export default combineReducers({

  userProfile,
  //other reducers that works...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
At index while creating store

```js
export const store = createStore(
    combineReducer,
    applyMiddleware(thunk) // choose you middleware....
    //initial state as per need
);
```

At reducer:

```js
import {
  FETCH_PROFILE,
  FETCH_PROFILE_SUCCESS,
  FETCH_PROFILE_FAIL
} from '../actions/profile';


export default function userProfile(state= {
  initialized: true,
  init:false,
  success:false,
  fail:false,
  
}, action) {
  switch(action.type) {

      case FETCH_PROFILE:{
       const message = action.message; 
          return Object.assign({}, state, { 
             init:true,
             success:false,
             fail:false,
             data:message,
          })
}
      }

      case FETCH_PROFILE_SUCCESS:{ 
      const data = action.data; 
          return Object.assign({}, state, { 
             init:false,
             success:true,
             fail:false,
             data:data,
          })
}

      case FETCH_PROFILE_FAIL:{ 
      const err = action.err; 
          return Object.assign({}, state, { 
             init:false,
             success:false,
             fail:true,
             data:err,
          })
}

      default:
        return state


  }
}
```

At Component:

```js
import React from 'react';
//use can use this if required.
//import withStyles from 'isomorphic-style-loader/lib/withStyles';
import {connect } from 'react-redux';
import { profileActions}  from '../../actions/profile';
//import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';  

class ProfilePage extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state{
        success:false;
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {

      this.props.getUserProfile();
    }
    
    componentWillReciveProps(nextprop){
     if(nextprop.success===true){
     this.setState({success==true});
     }
    }

  render() {
    
    return (
      {(this.state.success)?<div>this.props.profile.data.yourdata</div>:<div>Loading....</div>}
    );
  }
}


function mapStateToProps(state) {
   return {
    profile: state.userProfile
  };
}




export default connect(mapStateToProps,{profileActions
})(ProfilePage);
```

At action:

```js
export const FETCH_PROFILE = 'FETCH_PROFILE';
export const FETCH_PROFILE_SUCCESS = 'FETCH_PROFILE_SUCCESS';
export const FETCH_PROFILE_FAIL = 'FETCH_PROFILE_FAIL';


export function getUserProfile() {


           return (dispatch) => {
                dispatch(getUserProfileStart(const message:"fetch start"));
                const config2 = {
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
                    credentials: 'include',
                    body: ``,
                };

              fetch('http://api.example.com/profile/',config2)
              .then((resp) => resp.json())
              .then(function(data) {        

               dispatch(getUserProfileSuccess(data));
               return 0;

            }).catch(function(error){

                return dispatch(getUserProfileError(error));
            })

}
}


function getUserProfileSuccess(data) {
    return {
        type: FETCH_PROFILE_SUCCESS,
        data
    }
}

function getUserProfileStart(message) {
    return {
        type: FETCH_PROFILE,
        message
    }
}

function getUserProfileError(err) {
    return {
        type: FETCH_PROFILE,
        err
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the above code. This should solve your problems